Terminal.gui : Pb initializing CursesDriver on Ubuntu
I build a small Console App on .NET8.0 with Terminal.gui  1.17.1. It works well on Windows 11.
I publish it using linux-x64 as target runtime, in an autonomous unique file.
In copy files on my local Ubuntu 22.04.3 LST (I upgrade update etc ...)
When I run my code I get :
./ConsoleTerminalGui01
Unhandled exception. System.Exception: Curses failed to initialize, the exception is: Unable to load shared library 'libdl.so' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider using a tool like strace. If you're using glibc, consider setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable:
/home/jpblanc/Sandbox/terminal/libdl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/home/jpblanc/Sandbox/terminal/liblibdl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/home/jpblanc/Sandbox/terminal/libdl.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/home/jpblanc/Sandbox/terminal/liblibdl.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

   at Terminal.Gui.CursesDriver.Init(Action terminalResized)
   at Terminal.Gui.Application.InternalInit(Func`1 topLevelFactory, ConsoleDriver driver, IMainLoopDriver mainLoopDriver, Boolean calledViaRunT)
   at Terminal.Gui.Application.Init(ConsoleDriver driver, IMainLoopDriver mainLoopDriver)
   at ConsoleTerminalGui01.ManageOracleStagings.Main(String[] args) in C:\....\ManageOracleStagings.cs:line 25
Aborted

Here is the code of ManageOracleStagings.cs
namespace ConsoleTerminalGui01
{
  partial class ManageOracleStagings
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      /* Lecture du paramétrage
       */
      AppParams appParams;
      Dictionary<string, string> cmdLineParams = new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "staging", null } };
      GetManagedParams(args, out appParams, cmdLineParams);

      Application.Init(); // Line 25
      Application.Run(new ConsoleTerminalGui01.MainWin(appParams, cmdLineParams));
      Application.Shutdown();
    }
  }
}

What I try so far
Try to install libdl
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libc6 libc6-dev
sudo apt-get install libncurses5 libncursesw5 libtinfo5

